# Useless Interface alternative needed

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, architecture, object-oriented-analysis

In a system I have an  Interface `IVIew` for a View and a explicit Implementation `TextView`. The TextView also implements the Observer Interface so it can be updated on changes in a Model. So now I can use `IView` wherever I need a non explicit View. This might be a Controller which hold a `IView` or an abstract Factory for platform independent views.

[image]

So now I'm confused if the interface even makes sense here. Except from method declarations like init() or setModel() **there won't be functionality which will be called from somewhere else because the View gets updates implicitly from a model**. I also thought about making IView an abstract class, implementing Observer with members every View should know.
Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not totally clear what problem you're trying to solve here.  It sounds like you're saying that `IView` serves no purpose because there are no useful methods on it.  In which case, why does it exist in the first place?

Comment: I created the ´IView´-inteface because I want to keep communicating with my Views independent from type of UI(GUI, TUI) and platform. I also want my View to be its Controllers property (platform independent) but the communication with the View currently just happens by getting updates from the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a view by definition needs data from a different data source in MV* patterns, I'd let `IView` extend `Oberserver`. This provides enough flexibility for changes and controllers can talk against a generic view, which is easily extendable.